# Django Field 'id' expected a number but got '<string>'

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make a category page for my Django project. Everything works fine when I tested the url; but when I try to pass in the category object that filter the posts, I get this error: `Field 'id' expected a number but got '<string>'`.

"category" is a foreign key in my Post model and I understand that the default that it passes is the id. How do I pass the string itself instead of the id?

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime, date


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, default='Uncategorized')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post, Category


class BlogView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    ordering = ['-updated_on'] 

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(BlogView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['categories'] = categories
        return context

def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
    return render(request, 'blog/categories.html', {'cats': cats, 'category_posts': category_posts})
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('blog', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/', views.CategoryView, name='category'),
    ...
]
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    | {{ cats }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}   
    ...

    <div class="header-container" >
        <h1>{{ cats }}</h1>
    </div>

    ...
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changein urls.py,

```
    path('category/<str:cats>/', views.CategoryView, name='category'),
```

to

```
    path('category/<int:cats>/', views.CategoryView, name='category'),
```

to force parameter to integer type.

When you make filter query

```
category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
```

category is the foreign key, so the query will take the primary key of category and compare with the input parameter "cats" and it has integer value.

Comment: And avoid duplicate categories with `unique=True` in the params of the field `name` in the model `Category`

Answer (score 0):

However with django 3.0.6 and python 3.6.9, I had the same issue with simple CBV like TemplateView or ListView which does not require mandatory parameter.

The url below works.

```
path('blog/dummy', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
```

Whereas the one below, doesn't, the error: *Field 'id' expected a number but got 'blog_list'* is thrown. Where *blog_list* is the name of the url...

```
path('blog', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
```

The addition of anything with a slash(/) after the path works?!...