# Page not found [404] in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get all the post, posted in the same category. So my url looking like this, '..../category/Sports' where sports is a category. But if I enter this url, I got page, not found. I have also a html file called category. I also made makemigrations and migrate a several times

My views.py file:

```
from .models import Post, Category
..............
def CatView(request, cats):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
    return render(request,'category.html',{"cats":cats, 'posts':posts})
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('',HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('add-post/',  Addblogview.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('add-category/',  AddCategoryview.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatethePost.as_view(), name='add_task'),
    path('article/delete/<int:pk>', DeleteThePost.as_view(), name='delete_task'),
    path('category/<int:cats>', CatView, name='category'),
]
```

If I change **<str:cats>** I ended up with ValueError `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Sports'`

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='uncategorized')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail',args=str(self.id))

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "|" + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail',args=str(self.id))
```

My category.html:

```
{{cats}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set a primary key for `Category`, so the primary key becomes the numeric ID of the row, and the `ForeignKey` in `Post` needs to match that.  You really want to set `primary_key=True` when you create the name field in `Category`.

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__theblog_category.name after migration

Comment: you must have more than 1 row with the same category. PKs are unique per table.

Comment: where to set `primary_key=True`?

Comment: In the `name = models.CharField( ... )` line.  If you already have a database with records, you won't be able to do that.  You'd need to recreate the database.

Comment: I''m getting thousands of error now, Django is worst

Comment: go to the app and in the migrations file remove the file that creates your issue. You can check id(series of numbers) is mentioned in the error. if you cannot find, remove last few migrations clear the error, go to the admin panel and depopulate all model objects and then follow what @Azmain1234 has said

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826418/django-django-field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-string this is looking like code. But i got no help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just add a slash to the end of your URL in urls.py and try again? :)